# Java benefits of using a 3rd party socket Library

Tags: java, sockets, frameworks, netty

I guess that question won't be appreciated in here, but I need some solid explanation.

I have a client-server chat application, that is near completion which is build with Java's socket libraries.

So my question is how much would it improve, and in what aspects, if I use a 3rd party socket library like netty, if someone can list some benefits and tell me if it is worth refactoring my code with that library, i would appreciate it.

The only thing I can think of atm is, it would handle all cases I might be missing in my code, what else, thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit late for making that kind of decision. Using 3rd party libraries is supposed to make development more convenient by not trying to reinvent the wheel, they are tested and usually the version you get already includes bug fixes that have been reported by many developers using them etc. I don't think it's worth refactoring to use one at any cost, as long as your thing works and the test coverage is good you should be ok with your code, you just have done some extra work that you didn't have to do :)